# Google Analytics - Bounced User Landing Page

Tags: google-analytics, landing-page, user-engagement, bounce

In Google Analytics, is it possible to see the top landing pages for bounced users? That is, I want to see the pages users are landing on, not interacting with, and then leaving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is quite simple to achieve in Google Analytics...

From your 'Reporting' tab in GA:-

- Set your time period.
- Navigate to Behaviour > Site Content > Landing Pages
- Click on 'Bounce Rate' to sort by those pages with the highest bounce rate.